# Adding a specific components to the Spring Context when creating a facade component

Tags: java, spring, testing

Rather than making some of my classes `@Autowire` many small `@Component`s, I wanted to create a single `@Component` that would collect and just forward to the smaller `@Component`s.

Coding itself isn't too difficult, but when it comes to testing, it becomes cumbersome because now I have to add it to the `@ContextConfiguration(classes)`.  Is there a way of doing it so I don't have to manage it individually?

Using `@ComponentScan` adds the whole package which I may not want because it will trigger more `@MockBean` to be created.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you are looking for is a combination of `@Configuration + @Bean`. Instead of marking all your nested subcomponents with @Component you can initialize the complete chain via `@Bean` and work with simple pojo-s instead of spring managed beans. At the end of course the end result will be a spring managed bean, but the initialization process, you can initialize it from anywhere with spring , or without spring.

With regards of ComponetScan. Usualy if I want to load only a certain section I create annotation with explicit patter of the conponenbt scan I want and then I use it accross the domain I want.

Example, lets say we have two sets of Mapper classes one is regarding Order the other is regarding inventory. I can create annotation `@EnableOrderMappers` and annotation `@EnableInventoryMappers` with appropriate component scann annotation on them.